# Failing to pass a Field.choices integer parameter to a function in view.py (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm attempting to pass a [Field.choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) integer parameter into a function in view.py. However, I can't seem to make this work.

Specifically, in my case, I want to use the Field.choices integer parameter to decide which state the user would like a particular object to switch to. Currently, I have a view functions for every type of state change, and they are all identical. So, the goal of this is to tend towards code that is more DRY.

**EXAMPLE SITUATION**

Here is some HTML code (which has access to a diagnostic and diagnostic_filter object):

```
            <a href="{% 
              url reports.views.mark
              diagnostic.id,
              diagnostic_filter.FALSE %}" 
              class="btn"> 
              False Positive 
            </a>
```

Initially, the user click on this type of button/ link.

I would like to pass the integer diagnostic_filter.FALSE (which is one of three possible states of diagnostic_filter) to a generalised "mark" function:

```
def mark(request, diagnostic_id, state):
   #Code to change state...
```

This "mark" function, as shown, should go through and change the state of the diagnostic filter object (which is related to the diagnostic object) to FALSE.

Here is my attempt at the corresponding line in urlconf.py:

```
url(r'^diagnostic/(?P<diagnostic_id>\d+)/(?P<state>\d+)/$', 'mark'),
```

Here is my model of my diagnostic_filter class in models.py:

```
class DiagnosticFilter(models.Model):
FALSE = 1
LOW = 2
HIGH = 3
STATES = (
    (FALSE, 'False Positive'),
    (LOW, 'Low Priority'),
    (HIGH, 'High Priority'),
)
state = models.IntegerField(choices=STATES)
```

I'm passing diagnostic and diagnostic_filter to my template using:

```
return render_to_response(
    'reports/diagnostic.html',
    {diagnostic,
     diagnostic_filter},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

Is this the best way around this? Am I doing anything wrong? It seems that when I load the page with the button I get an error on the lines of **Reverse for '[FILE URL HERE].mark' with arguments '(108383, Undefined)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likelihood is that you *don't* actually have access to the `diagnostic_filter` object, or it isn't the class `DiagnosticFilter`. The error you're getting shows that the template is seeing the value `diagnostic_filter.FALSE` as 'Undefined', which is odd because you don't show that value in your model, and Django's usual behaviour is to show unknown attributes as `None`. Can you show how you're passing `diagnostic_filter` to the temmplate?

Comment: My template definitely has access to diagnostic_filter. I've used it successfully for quite a while within my template and yesterday before posting the question double checked that diagnostic_filter.FALSE gave a value of 1. I did this by inserting <h1>{{ diagnostic_filter.FALSE }}</h1>. Please refer back to my question to see how I'm passing diagnostic_filter. Cheers.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Turns out on occasion diagnostic_filter is not defined. This was done on purpose (in other words, it was a design decision only found within the implementation code). Thanks for your time.